# Page Number even though \maketitle command excluded

Tags: page-numbering

since I don't know how to create the wanted title page, I decided to leave out the \maketitle command after \begin{document} since the teacher is not expecting the title. Now I am having the problem, that the counting starts on page 2, excluding my first page to being numbered. How can I still include a page number of page 1?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[hyperref]{acl2020}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{titling}
%\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{placeins}
\renewcommand{\UrlFont}{\ttfamily\small}


\usepackage{microtype}

% Determine if the image is too wide for the page.


% Resize figures that are too wide for the page.



\aclfinalcopy % Uncomment this line for the final submission
%\def\aclpaperid{***} %  Enter the acl Paper ID here


\newcommand\BibTeX{B\textsc{ib}\TeX}

\title{Coursework 1}

\begin{document}
 %\maketitle
 \begin{titlingpage}
\maketitle
\end{titlingpage}
 \pagestyle{plain}


\section{Task A(a.):


    \section{Task A(a.)

%References - needs no heading
\bibliography{bib}
\bibliographystyle{apa}


\end{document}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please post a compilable code reproducing your problem. This being said, the `titling` package yields tools to customise the `\maketitle` command.

Comment: it should be compilable now thank you. I tried titling, but as far as I understood does it create a title page, and then starts counting. Is there a way in which I just have the first page numbered without adding a titlepage?

Comment: I think  `titling` does not necessarily create a title page (check in the documentation). This probably depends on the document class

Answer (score 0):

This should meet your requirements
--Title Page will not have any page number
--Page numbering will start from next page(after title page) at Pg.1 and so on

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{fullpage}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}

    \title{Some Random Title}
    \author{Author Name}
    \date{}

    \begin{document}


    \maketitle
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \newpage
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \rfoot{Page \thepage}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    Some random words.    
    \newpage
    Some random words on second page.

    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Title page non numbered, text in another page as page 1:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
Your title author and whatever  here. The format and content is up to you. 
\end{titlepage}
\lipsum[1-10] % dummy text 
\end{document}
```

2) Title in the same page that text, starting in page 1:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\title{Your title}
\author{Your Name}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1-10] % dummy text 
\end{document}
```